# No permission to perform current operation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-live-api

I am working with Graph API with live_videos edge. As am able to get the response for the live_videos method with the developer account credentials. The app got approved with "publish_actions" permissions and it's live. Even though when am trying to login with other credentials of Facebook account to login and get the response for graph API with Live_videos edge.

I am giving Publish_Actions,email, public_profile permissions. Do I need any more permission to get the successful response and generate the stream RTMP URL for live? It's getting error as:

> {"error":{"message":"(#100) No permission to perform current operation.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"D2bY3K8zhFt"}}

What am I missing?

Comment: What API call are you making?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.